# Is it possible to read a ruby hash from one file into another and then use its values?

Tags: ruby, hash

## Background

I have a project structure in which I have an .rb file which contains data in a hash which is not the only thing in the file:

```rb
name "vm"
description "Configuration file for the Demo VM"
default_attributes(
    custom_demo: {
        verticals: {
            fashion: true,
            automotive: false,
            fsi: false,
            custom: true
        },
        channels: {
            b2b: true,
            b2c: true
        },
        geos: [
            'us_en'
        ]
    },
    infrastructure: {
        php: {
            version: '7.3',
            port: 9000
        },
        webserver: {
            http_port: 80,
            ssl_port: 443
        },
        database: {
            user: 'magento',
            password: 'password',
            name: 'magento'
        },
        elasticsearch: {
            use: true,
            version: '6.x',
            memory: '1g',
            port: 9200,
            plugins: ['analysis-phonetic', 'analysis-icu']
        },
        mailhog: {
            use: true,
            port: 10000
        },
        webmin: {
            use: true,
            port: 20000
        },
        samba: {
            use: true,
            shares: {
                composer_credentials: true,
                image_drop: true,
                web_root: true,
                app_modules: true,
                multisite_configuration: true,
                app_design: true
            }
        }
    }
```

In another ruby script, I need use the values from this `default_attributes` hash to do other things.

## My Question

What's the best way to make use of the above ruby hash in another ruby script?

## What I've Tried

First I tried using `load()` to just "load in" the file with the hash.  That threw an issue because of the first two lines:

```rb
name "vm"
description "Configuration file for the Demo VM"
```

So, I figured I'd read it as a string or an array and skip the first two lines:

```rb
data_string = ''
data = File.readlines(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + '/environments/vm.rb').drop(2).each do |line| 
  data_string += line
end
data_hash = JSON.parse(data_string)
print data_hash
```

This approach does two things I'm not fond of: First, it prints the result to the screen, and second, it errors out with:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 751: unexpected token at 'verticals: { (JSON::ParserError)
```

It was at this point that I began to doubt my approach and wonder if what I'd like to do is even possible. To clarify, ideally, after figuring out how to parse the above file in another script, I'd be able to use something from the hash, like:

```rb
default_attributes[:infrastructure][:php][:version]
# => 7.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to read the hash directly from this file is *doable*, but *messy*. I think you should approach it from a different angle instead. Rather than trying to read the hash from this file directly, move the hash into its own file, and read it from both places. So:

1. Put the hash in its own file:

   ```
   # my_hash.rb

   MyHash = {
     # put the hash content here
   }
   ```
2. Load it from the vm config file:

   ```
   # vm_config.rb

   require_relative './my_hash.rb'
   name "vm"
   description "Configuration file for the Demo VM"
   default_attributes(MyHash)
   ```
3. Load it from any other file as well:

   ```
   # other_file.rb

   require_relative './my_hash.rb'
   puts MyHash
   # => hash will print, it has been loaded
   ```

---

Just as an excercise (don't do this!), here is how I would read the hash from the file directly:

```
# other_file.rb

# dummy methods:
def name(*args); end;
def description(*args); end

# intercept the hash and assign it to a global
def default_attributes(hash)
  $my_hash = hash
end

# require the vm config file, running the above functions:
require_relative './vm_config.rb'

puts $my_hash
# => prints the hash
```

Comment: Style nitpick: `MyHash` should be `MY_HASH`, as it is a non-module constant.

Comment: One might `prepend(Module.new { def default_attributes(hash); ...; end })` store the hash and call `super` :)

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.  Unfortunately for me, I don't think it'll solve my actual problem: I'm using Chef, and the stand-alone hash is actually a set of environment attributes which have to be loaded onto the chef node.  When I use this approach (understandably), I get a "cannot load such file" error because chef is trying to load my required hash file but it's never transferred to the node. I'll have to try to work around that.  In the meantime, I'll accept this answer and thank you for the effort in explaining it.

Comment: The workaround I used was to convert the suggested stand-alone ruby hash to json and then essentially write the vm_config.rb file out using that json file.  This gives me a file chef doesn't depend on that I can read into my Vagrant file for additional use, but still provides chef with the .rb file it needs to run.  The accepted solution was immensely helpful in showing the approach for this.